# Android app indexing without a webpage

Tags: android, google-search

Is it possible? I want to list my application results with using TmDB API not with a webpage. My main target is showing my app results in Google search application.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to index app only content. However, it seems as if Google plans to support it in the future (it is currently tested with selected developers). You can express your interest using the following form: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/app-only